# How to do something when ( for in ) will execute javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following code that checks the values of json variable

```
var user_data={
  name:"user",
  age:10,
  blocked: false,
  active: true
}
for(let key in user_data){
  if(key=='active' && user_data[key]==true){
    //do something
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is something like to do exception in the last loop such as this example that checks the last loop before exit

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5];
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  if(i>=array.length-1){
    //I'm in the last loop to do this exception 
  }
}
```

Edit:

Don't let this example confuse you. The main question is - how to check - is I'm inside the last loop of (for in) or not to do my exception.

Comment: its normal array such as array=[1,2,3,4,5]; I put the bellow example to explain my needs in deferent way but the main needs is how to check im in the last loop of (for in) or im not.

Comment: Do not use the for/in statement to loop through arrays where index order is important. Use the for statement instead. so if you want to put check based on key , they way you used for/in is right . but if you want to put check on last key always its not good idea to use for/in as order of key can be changed

Comment: So how to do that with normal for loop? I tried to do that but i got errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if you are in the last loop of `for..in` you can use below logic:

```js
let i = 0;
const user_data = {name:"user",age:10,blocked:!1,active:!0};
const length = Object.keys(user_data).length;

for (let key in user_data) {
   const last = i === length - 1;
   console.log(`${key}: ${user_data[key]}`);
   if (last) {
      console.log('This is the last loop')
      // Your logic here...
   }
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to know if you have the last key in the object you're iterating over. Object key order is not static like an array, so I think you'll want to get the number of keys, and then count in your loop, for example:

```js
var user_data = {
  name:"user",
  age:10,
  blocked: false,
  active: true,
}

let numKeys = Object.keys(user_data).length;
let keyCounter = 1;

for (let key in user_data) {
  if (keyCounter === numKeys) {
    console.log(`last key is "${key}"`);
  }
  keyCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var user_data={
  name:"user",
  age:10,
  blocked: false,
  active: true
}
var keyArray = Object.keys(user_data)
for (var i=0 ; i< keyArray.length; i++ ) {
  if (i== keyArray.length -1) {
    //your code here 
    lastKey =  keyArray[i]
    console.log(lastKey) 
  }
}
```

Comment: you can create a var like : var keyArray = Object.keys(user_data) , see above code edited

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

**This will make your code as clean as it could be with the help of util function. You can optimize your util function as ur need.**

> **Generator, yield**

```
 var user_data = {
      name: "user",
      age: 10,
      blocked: false,
      active: true
    };

    for (let [value, key, isLast, index] of toArray(user_data)) {
      if (isLast) console.log([value, key, isLast, index]);
    }
```

```js
const toArray = obj => {
  const MAX_LENGTH = Object.keys(obj).length;
  let array = {};
  array[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    let counter = 0;
    for (let key in obj) {
      counter++;
      yield [obj[key], key, counter === MAX_LENGTH, counter - 1];
    }
  };
  return array;
};



var user_data = {
  name: "user",
  age: 10,
  blocked: false,
  active: true
};

for (let [value, key, isLast, index] of toArray(user_data)) {
  console.log([value, key, isLast, index]);
}
```